# Numbered/bulleted list don't show correctly when no text is added

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

I've been confused whenever I create an numbered/bulleted list, since in the preview (and the final result) it shows as nested until I start to write something in the next element. Although this is a cosmetic change, it might confuse new users until they discover that there are some glitches in the markdown.

```
 - List item
 -
```

This shows in the preview as:

[image: Bulleted list in preview and final result]

The same happens with numbered lists:

```
 1. List item
 2.
```

[image: Numbered list in preview and final result]

There is a space after the dot/dash in both scenarios, witch creates non-standard response by [some of markdown syntax](http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/?markdown=%20-%20One%0D%0A%20-%20&src=1&dest=2). In both cases after you add some text to the list it render correctly.

I reckon this is a cosmetic problem rather than a serious bug, but there isn't cosmetic tags.

Comment: This has always somewhat bothered me, but then I remember, who would leave an empty item in a bulletted of numbered list? It stands out more this way.

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn Remember that the difference between a nested list and non-nested list is just a single stroke of the spacebar and I've had to crack my head before discovering that I just had to continue typing to get the expected result ;)

Comment: It might confuse non-seasoned users until they write something in the list element.

Comment: Still: thumbs up for actually looking at how things are rendered! (I often only look at the preview when I'm kind of done, but just too many don't seem to look at the preview, or the final result.)

Comment: Huh, why are you using my avatar? Please don't.

Comment: @Arjan wanted to change it for some time now... and yours was pink enough for me :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odd as it might seem, this is very much by design, I think. A Markdown list item needs content to be recognized as such. Without content, it's just an odd/unspecified continuation of the previous line.

Even more: most Markdown implementations handle it like this. You can see for yourself on [the Babelmark Markdown Testbed](http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/?markdown=+-+One%0D%0A+-).

(Note that it's not just the preview; the preview matches the actual rendering just fine. Also, changing the Stack Exchange implementation to make it easier, will break rendering when using other engines, for those who're using [the data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/).)

Comment: You were missing a extra space that I add in my tests. When I add the [extra space](http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/?markdown=+-+One%0D%0A+-+&src=1&dest=2) there isn't a standard way to show the dash. Some shows the `<space>-<space>` as such, others creates a `<p>` tag, and Discount and PEG shows the `<li>` tags.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't change anything really? Then it's undefined behavior, and fixing it in the Stack Exchange implementation will yield undefined results in others?

Comment: I more or less gave up when I found out that not all markdowns behave differently under this condition.